# How can I export my org file to be locally exactly like the github version?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am new to emacs. In addition, I decided to learn org-mode which seems to be fantastic.

I wrote this `.org` file that you can check [here](https://github.com/pdelfino/public-notes/blob/main/learning-org-mode.org). In Github, the file has this appearance:

[image]

In Emacs, it has a different appearance as the source:

[image]

I would like to see the content locally as it will be presented on Github.

I tried using `C-c C-e` with options like .HTML and .odt. However, the output files do not look like the Github one.

Is there something that I could do to get what I want?

Ideally, it would be good to have a "previewer" instead of really exporting a file just to see how it would look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am no expert at this, but I guess github uses its own CSS, and ultimately renders html. So I guess there has to be some kind of export involved.

I know about two easy options, of which I would recommend [grip-mode](https://github.com/seagle0128/grip-mode) (requires the python [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) package). The other option [gfm-mode](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) (appears to rely on deprecated packages [Docter or Marked 2](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode#github-flavored-markdown-gfm)).

Looking back at [this PR](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/14120), I see there is also [vmd-mode](https://melpa.org/#/vmd-mode).

Comment: I believe that they use [org-ruby](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby) for exporting to HTML (plus a ton of CSS and JS).