# How can I live-preview org-mode for readme files?

Tags: org-mode, previewing

I am using `org-mode` to format readme files. When I commit a `README.org` file into `github.com`, I am able to see its formatted preview. But since I make a lot of changes, I have to keep commit to see its final preview.

=> `Markdown` has some editors where, while you are making change into `markdown file` you can see its final preview in real-time; example: (https://github.com/MacDownApp/macdown).

Is there any live-preview approach for `org-mode` as well? Could it be done within `emacs`?

Only approach I was able to come up is use https://github.com/GeneKao/orgmode-latex-templates to convert it into `pdf` for preview after each save.

Comment: For a very good alternative to the github flavored markdown live-preview, there is the [grip-mode](https://melpa.org/#/grip-mode) package. For additional options see the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/66285/26163).

Comment: Can I apply grip-mode for org files as well?

Comment: Yes, (as a comment here on SE can not have less than 12 characters, let me additionally mention that) the question in the link is also about org-mode specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try exporting `README.org` as html and view it in a browser.

Simplest is `C-c C-e h h` (bound to `org-html-export-to-html`) which produces a basic html file. If you need more than this for testing, you could tweak templates and css as described in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-Export.html), and there are various other packages for changing the output on [melpa](https://melpa.org/) (e.g. [ox-twbs](https://melpa.org/#/ox-twbs)).

For a live preview, there is [org-preview-html](https://github.com/jakebox/org-preview-html/) which should be able to preview the generated html in emacs (but I've not tested it)

Comment: This does not show the images on the html. Is there any way to show them too?

Comment: it should work with images. maybe check the img tags in the generated html to see if there is an issue with the paths?

Comment: original path is `[[file:/docs/gui1.png]]` but its formatted as `gui1.ping` in the html file. I can see the image in the github using the same format

Comment: @alper, try an alternative - export to html5 via pandoc.

Comment: @Ian Thanks I will look into it.  Do you have any advice for the `export to html5 via pandoc.` approach?

Comment: Nothing important; may depend on what you write in such file.

Comment: I am sorry for a late comment but afterwards can we convert html to pdf? or shoud I directly convert org to pdf?